# Replicate rows in a 2D tensor y[i] times, where i is the index in another tensor y?

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for a tf operation that replicates the elements in a input tensor x by y[i] times, where i is the index in a second tensor. More precisely, the operation should achieve the following:

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]])
y = tf.constant([3, 2, 4])

z = <operation>(x, y) # [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4],
                         [2, 5], [2, 5], 
                         [3, 6], [3, 6], [3, 6], [3, 6]]
```

What operation can I use? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is to build a 1-D tensor of indices replicated according to `y` and then do a `tf.gather`:

```
def repeat(t, times):
    num_elements = tf.shape(t)[0]

    def cond_fn(i, _):
        return i < num_elements

    def body_fn(i, indices_ta):
        repeated_i = tf.tile(i[tf.newaxis], times[i, tf.newaxis])
        return (i + 1, indices_ta.write(i, repeated_i))

    indices_ta = tf.TensorArray(times.dtype, num_elements, infer_shape=False)
    _, indices_ta = tf.while_loop(
        cond_fn,
        body_fn,
        loop_vars=(0, indices_ta))

    return tf.gather(t, indices_ta.concat())
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. That's a working solution. However I am worried about performance - isn't the while loop performance hungry? If so, is there a solution without a while loop?

Comment: I.e. the construction of the 1-D tensor of indices [3, 2, 4] to [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2] without a while loop

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do that without a while loop (other than rolling a custom TF op from scratch). You could vary the implementation slightly by indexing into `t` directly (or better into a `TensorArray` with `t` slices), but it's hard to say if that is going to be more efficient.